# How to implement message ordering in Spring Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Kafka for my project development. I am using a topic which has:

`partitions : 5`

`min.insync.replicas: 3`

***So whatever messages have producer sent,  in the same order I need to process messages from Kafka Consumer.***

I have gone through some documentation and it was given there that we need to use key in producer so it will go to a particular partition.
***I am new to Kafka and not sure how will I implement this.***

Following are the properties for Kafka Consumer:

```
 props.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
 props.put(GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "prj_1");
 props.put(KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
 props.put(VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
 props.put(AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
 props.put(ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, Boolean.FALSE);
```

And following code is for KafkaListener:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${test.topic}")
public void consume(
  @NotNull final ConsumerRecord<String, String> cr,
  @Payload final String payload,
  final Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
try{
    final XYZObject xyzObject =
    objectMapper.readValue(payload, XYZObject.class);
    final Response response = processPayload(xyzObject);
    publishResponseToKafka(response, xyzObject);
    log.info(
        "publishResponseToKafka() took =\"{}\"ms", Duration.between(pblshTime, 
     Instant.now()).toMillis());
  } finally {
     acknowledgment.acknowledge();
  }
 }
```

Looking forward to hearing from you all.

Thanks.

Comment: Been answered many times: Consumption order is not guaranteed over more than one partition. Keys help partition data, not consumption ordering (unless you explicitly assign a consumer to handle single partitions)

Comment: Also not clear your use-case. Does XYZ and time T have any relation to new_XYZ at time T+1? If not, does order _really_ matter?

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer XYZ and time T was part of my example. these are not related to my question. I have situation where I need to process the messages in same order when it was published by producer. So if producer has produced e.g. msg1, msg2, msg3, msg4 and msg5  in following order:
Produced:  msg2 -> msg3 -> msg1 -> msg5  -> msg4
Then I consumer should receive messages in same order:
Consumer:  msg2 -> msg3 -> msg1 -> msg5  -> msg4

Considering 5 partition.

Comment: If they all have the same key, then they're forced to be ordered in that way, as pointed out